# Disk space implications of setting MySQL column value to NULL instead of 0 or ''

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to understand the best way to handle columns which are mostly empty in terms of **disk-space** and **index-performance**. Is there a difference between putting in all empty places NULL vs '' (for varchar / text) vs 0 (for int).

Thanks.

Comment: [Possibly  A Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015990/mysql-integer-0-vs-null)

Comment: @Thanga thanks for the ref it is similar, but I'm interested to hear about disk-space and index building implications. Will clarify

Comment: in addition to my answer below, my advice is that this sounds like a case of "premature optimization"  This is not really worth your time to worry about.  Just design schema that makes sense.  I guarantee you that this will not be your biggest bottleneck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, using NULL will not take up less space than an empty `VARCHAR` or `INT` field. In fact it may take up **more** space. Here's why:

A `VARCHAR` is stored as a size + value.  The number of bytes used for the size depends on the max storage of the `VARCHAR`. `VARCHAR(255)` requires one byte, `VARCHAR(65536)` requires two bytes and so on.

So that `VARCHAR(255)` column takes up one byte even if you store an empty string. The following table would take a minimum of one byte per row (plus some other possible overhead depending on storage engine).

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  a VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

To save `NULL` values, MySQL uses a bitmask for each row. Up to 8 nullable columns can be stored per byte. So if you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  a VARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

Would take a minimum of two bytes per row. Storing `NULL` just sets the bit, it's already reserved whether you use it or not. The byte for the `VARCHAR`'s size is still used for each row even if the column is set to `NULL`.

Comment: Good answer, does this apply to MySQL & ms SQL server?

Comment: I know this is true for MySQL, but I make no claims to know others -- this answer seems to indicate it's similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server

Comment: @GavinTowey good answer, but I assume the bitmask you mentioned helps MySQL manage the indexes more efficiently? If so, wouldn't that result in less space in cases there's an index on that column?

Comment: It doesn't.  I'm not exactly sure what it does internally, but this quick test shows that NULL in an index doesn't take up any less space. http://pastebin.ca/2247977

Comment: I don't know mechanics in postgres, but result similar - if I replace '', 0 and so on with nulls, database become bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is maybe (though it shouldn't matter), nulls may take up less disk-space, though the space saving will probably be tiny (though even tiny savings will add up).
Unless disk space is very tightly constrained I wouldn't worry about it (disk space is a lot cheaper than programmer time).
Also, null and 0 (or ''), are semantically different, so shouldn't be used interchangeably, certainly not for a theoretical (or very small) performance gain.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229805/how-much-disk-space-is-needed-to-store-a-null-value-using-postgresql-db) for more detail.

I don't think indexing will be greatly affected, there may be a slight speed improvement.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070329/query-performance-with-null) for more detail.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471367/when-to-use-null-in-mysql-tables) deals specifically with MySQL and null performance.

Comment: Why would a NULL take up less space than an empty VARCHAR field?

Comment: @GavinTowey - sorry, I was thinking of varchars with data, I'll amend my answer, they'd probably at most take 1 char less.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you have a fixed-width table (no `VARCHAR`, `VARBINARY`, `BLOB` or `TEXT`), it will probably make no difference.

In a variable-width table, a `NULL` will probably consume as much space as an empty `VARCHAR`.

If you have nearly all values `NULL` and only very few contain data, you could create a separate table which you join to.

So let's assume you have a list of people where only a few of them you have the birthdate.

So instead of

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, birthday DATE)
```

you could do

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE birthdates (id INT UNSIGNED, birthday DATE NOT NULL)
```

and query the data with a LEFT JOIN.

If there are applications which need to access the table in the old format, you could define a view.